# Is it ok to use the text on a button to determine current state?

Tags: vb.net, button, state, monitor

I have been using the text to determine the button state and want to know if it is generally accepted ?

I have a datagrid view with a list of items and a "Done" Button. When the user clicks the done button the cell is highlighted green to mark it is done.

I then change the button text to "Undo". So whenever the user scrolls over a "Green" Cell the button text changes to Undo.

I use that text to determine what to do when the button is clicked.

Is this ok? Or should I be using some kind of state monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is barely acceptable, but still bad.

Storing the status in a variable is not much more effort and would make the code more maintainable (dont mix processing and GUI).

When you somehow change the text of the button, you would have to adjust the checking too.

Also, this makes updating the GUI (multiple threads or the like) much easier.

Comment: Thanks!

Will try and avoid it. My current code is done like that, but if I have time I will change it.

Would you suggest creating a enum or a boolean in order to check the state?

Comment: If you only have two possible states, use a boolean. Creating a enum here isn't necessary.


If you have more than two, use a enum.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I favor in many cases to have private fields which indicate the logical state of controls, and properties which cause the properties of the controls themselves to be updated in a reasonably-timely fashion.  If there's one point of interaction with the properties of the controls themselves, and provided that the fields always represent a valid state, then non-UI-thread code can change the state of the controls without having to synchronize itself with the UI thread; it merely has to ensure that there's a request pending to update the controls when next convenient.

Although your particular example doesn't involve any threading issues, and thus doesn't really benefit from the ease of threading afforded by separating out control state from logical state, using the same pattern for cases requiring multi-threading support as for cases that don't will reduce the number of different patterns one has to deal with.  Additionally, if you use your own fields to represent the different states the controls can have, you can ensure that they will never represent an ambiguous or invalid state.  For example, if a piece of code set the button to "UNDO" rather than "Undo", some other code might decide that "it isn't 'Undo', so it should save", some might decide that "it isn't `Save`, so it should undo"`, some might do nothing, and some might squawk.  Further, it may be difficult to add any additional states or indications.  For example, one might want to add to the "Undo" button an indication of what would be undone.  If one uses fields to track states, one may be able to add such functionality without disturbing the field that distinguishes between "save" and "undo"; either add another field to keep track of what specific operation should be indicated when the undo button is shown, or else have the "update button text" routine use existing fields to determine that.